# How do you restart the video after you've scrolled down a certain amount of pixels?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to be able to stop and restart the video after a certain scroll point (let's say 80 pixels) and I've tried some stuff and it doesn't work. I'm pretty inexperience with JS so pls cut me some slack lol

This seemed like the solution for me but it would pause not restart and also it doesn't even work...

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    video.pause();
  } else {
    video.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me - https://jsfiddle.net/pfmbshy8/0/ (my version), https://jsfiddle.net/pfmbshy8/1/ (your version)

Comment: Note that you may need to click within the page at least once for `play()` to work, otherwise the video may not play automatically to prevent abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you shared, here is what the solution should look like. It works with the Codepen link I shared at the end of the answer.

If your video is from YouTube:

```
<iframe class="youtube-video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/glEiPXAYE-U?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Your JS should look something like below:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    $('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
  } else {
    $('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
  }
}
```

Video triggers credited to this pen: https://codepen.io/briangelhaus/pen/meeLRO

Demo: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/harishkotra/pen/oOeozR)

Comment: Curious - why did you separate `pauseVideo` and `playVideo` from the rest of the string? Just in order to emphasis and distinguish them?

Comment: @PhistucK yes. Just to show the difference of what's passed in the event.